# Function that modifies string based on unicode number

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that changes each character of the input string based on whether it s a letter or not. If it is a letter, the character should be set to '1' otherwise to '0'. For instance

```
change('abc123') returns ('111000')
change('12ab3') returns ('00110')
```

My try:

```
function change(para){

let newstring=para;
let unicodenum=String.fromCharCode();


for (i=0; i<para.length; i++){
  for (j=65; j<91; j++) {
    if (unicodenum[j] === para[i])
    {
      newstring.replace(/para[i]/g, "1")
    }
  else {
  newstring.replace(/para[i]/g, "0")
    }
    }
   }
return newstring
}
```

Right now, the string is not modified when invoked, but simply returned.

Comment: @GuyIncognito also need to link to that community wiki for RegEx.  Looks like she doesn't understand how regex works

Comment: you will need to explain what you mean by "unicode number".  if you need to deal with actual unicode sequences you may have to do something different.

Comment: `let unicodenum=String.fromCharCode()`  is same as `unicodenum = ""`. So, `unicodenum[j]` isn't doing anything

Comment: `str.replace(/\d/g,'0').replace(/[a-z]/ig, '1')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple one liner that will do what you needed.

I have used regrex, `/[0-9]/g,"0"` will replace all numbers with `0` and `/[a-z]/g,"1"` will replace all letters from `a-z` with `1`.

`/g` denotes the global flag that will replace all occurrences of `0-9` and `a-z`. We can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

`/[0-9]/g,"0"` is used before `/[a-z]/g,"1"` because you also want numbers to be converted to "0". If we first convert letters to numbers then everything in the string will become number and all you will get is `0`. So it has to be in this specific order only.

```js
let change=(string)=>string.replace(/[0-9]/g,"0").replace(/[a-z]/g,"1")
console.log(change('abc123'))
console.log(change('12ab3'))
```